# Replacing unique nested statement with regex or alternatives

Tags: php, regex

From the countless questions posted I know it's not possible/advisable to use regex to replace nested statements.

I'm wondering if it makes any difference in a case where statements are unique:

```
[if @test]TEST[if @second]SECOND[/if][/if]
```

I've gotten it work when the end blocks are also unique, which I know is clumsy workaround:

```
[if @test]TEST[if @second]SECOND[/if @second][/if @test]
$pattern = '%\[if @'.$dynamic.'.*?\](.*?)\[/if @'.$dynamic.'\]%s'; //Works with above
```

Is it possible to use regex without the end block being unique? Are there alternatives to regex that would accomplish this?

I would like to parse something like: [if @test]TEST[if @second]SECOND[/if][/if] with arbitrary nesting levels. If regex is not practical, can anyone suggest viable alternative in PHP?

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish?  Please give sample input with desired output.

Comment: I'll edit the question, but the goal is what it say to use regex to do the replacement without needing a unique endblock, just a unique beginning.

Comment: The problem isn't really with *nesting*, but with *arbitrary* nesting. For example, I can easily write a regex to parse the various parts of `a[b[c[d[e]f]g]h]i` if I know that the brackets will be nested exactly four deep, and each set of brackets has exactly one set nested immediately within it; but if the same regex needs to be able to handle `a[b[c]d[e[f[g]h[i[j[k[l]m[n]o]p]q]r]s[t]u]v]w`, then it can't be done with true regexes, and PHP doesn't support the kind of extensions that would make it possible.

Comment: Everything you're saying makes sense -- and that's what I've been discovering recently. I'm curious though, if regex can't do it is there even a viable alternative in PHP?

Comment: As Madbreaks says, you need to explain what you are trying to do with example output. PHP/PCRE does support matching arbitrarily nested structures (i.e. `(?R)`, `(?1)`, etc.) but these expressions can be a bit tricky to use. Its pretty easy to match either the innermost and outermost elements. Intermediate matches are also possible using a callback.

Comment: Updated the question -- hopes that's a bit clearer. I'm not glued to regex, more looking for viable alternative approaches in PHP to parse my sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a proper solution you should *tokenize* the string in to its basic components such as tags, comments, text and whatever else you have there. This step can be done with regex, and produces a *flat list* of tokens. Next you go trough the tokens building a *parse tree* with all the structure and details needed. (Both steps can be combined and done in one pass as well.)

That way everything is under your control and you don't need to reparse any part of the code.

On the other hand it can be done with regex, but then you are more limited, and you need to reparse the nested parts of the code for every added depth.

Since you asked for a *regex*, here is one to match such nested `if`s:

```
~
\[if\ @(\w++)]
(
    (?>
        (?: (?!\[if\ @\w++]|\[/if]) . )++
        |
        (?R)
    )*+
)
\[/if]
~xs
```

Comment: Yup. This is the one that will match the outermost IF element. +1